# is it possible to use "minifyenabled = true" in Android.MK or any replacement for that

Tags: android, android-build, android-make

I have an android studio based project.To reduce the resource I have used the

```
android {
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
    }
  }
```

It's working properly, The unused resources are removed from the built apk.

Now I want to build the same project using Android.mk file from the AOSP build.

Is it possible to use `minifyenabled = true` and other options in Android.MK or any replacement for that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `shrinkResources = true` too! minifyenabled will shortcut names methods and classes and mark unused resources, then shrinkResources actually removes that marked unused resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the same in my build.gradle file. and it works properly. I want to know is it possible to use in Android.mk file?

Comment: the question updated @MohammadL do you have any idea regarding this, please help me

Comment: sorry I don't work with  Android.mk yet

Comment: @MidhunPM Any solution for this question? I would like to do the same thing!